# Downloading a file directly through a server

Tags: amazon-web-services, download, server

I have 2 servers (A, B), and an external server (C). Server C only accepts requests from server B (IP authorization). I need to download a file from server C to server A as quickly as possible. Of course, I could download the file to server B and then to server A but the file is quite large and time is critical. Is there a way to directly download the file from server C to A using B as a "proxy" of some sort?

Comment: Are you looking to do this programmatically or manually via CLI? If programmatically, what language?

Comment: You could look at rsync - it supports password-less (key based authentication) log in & download

Answer (score 0):

You could install something like [tinyproxy](https://banu.com/tinyproxy/) on server B if you're doing a file transfer via HTTP or HTTPS. Something like that will probably be the quickest & easiest approach to take.

Another approach you could take would be to use [SSH port forwarding](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/PortForwarding) to create a temporary "dumb" proxy, which has the added flexibility of supporting pretty much any port/protocol you might need.  Suppose you wanted to use scp to copy the file.  You could do something like this:

1. On server A, issue an ssh command along these lines:

   > $ ssh -L 2222:hostC.example.com:22 hostB.example.com
2. In a separate session on server A, issue the following:

   > $ scp -P 2222 localhost:/path/to/file/on/hostC /path/to/target

Step #1 is creating a tunnel from port 2222 on server A to server B such that when something connects through it then server B will establish a connection to port 22 (the SSH/SCP port) on server C.

Step #2 uses that tunnel by connecting to port 2222 on the localhost to request the desired file.

If you consider this approach you might want to take a look at setting up an SSH authorized key between server A & B so that you don't need to be prompted for a password, and parameters like -f and/or -n (depending on the version of SSH being used) to put the first connection into the background.